# How to fix anonymous inner class in java

Tags: java, anonymous-class

The code below is an anonymous inner class, it works when I run it on NetBeans but when compiled in Unix, it creates class with $1.

Is there a way to fix this code to compile successfully in unix?

```
    File directory = new File("/SAMPLE");
    File files[] = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
      @Override
      public boolean accept (File pathname) {
          String name = pathname.getName();
          return name.startsWith("S") && pathname.isFile();
      }
    }

  );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Define _fix_. `$1` seems like the appropriate name to me. Why do you think it's not. Show us the compilation error.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Just found the problem, its not the anonymous inner class but my manifest.txt, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

> but when compiled in Unix, it creates class with $1.

It is compiling, that's how an anonymous inner class is compiled. Also, that's not a valid file path on Unix-like systems. You can use [`File.listRoots()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots--) to get a cross-platform root. Something like

```
File directory = new File(File.listRoots()[0],"SAMPLE");
```

And on Unix-like systems, that will represent "/SAMPLE".

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Already solved the problem, its not the anonymous inner class but the Manifest.txt, I just correct the main class.